# Custom share button with Google Plus API

Tags: javascript, google-plus

I'm trying to create a custom designed share icon for Google Plus that sits in an app that will be inside an iframe. The share should allow for text and an image.

I **cannot** use meta tags as these would sit in the iFrames parent, of which already has it's own tags for it's own sharing utils.

Can this be done, and if so how?

Thanks in advance!

PS. Google plus documentation is so over complicated and sucks!

Comment: You have to specify the the details in the HTML of the page being shared. Google gets the details by making an HTTP request to the URL and parsing the response HTML. Google will not fetch a page within an iframe of the shared URL.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't fully understand your setup but I guess this will work for you:

```
<a href="https://plus.google.com/share?url=YOUR_URL" onclick="window.open(this.href, 'Google+', 'width=490,height=530'); return false;">
  <img src="IMAGE_PATH" alt="Google+" title="Google+"/>
</a>
```

It'll open a share window that you can enter your comment, and select the people that you want to share.

Comment: Thanks, but do I add custom text and a custom image?

Comment: Ah, sorry, I missed that part. I just updated the example above.